# Redirecting to /folder/{param1}/{param2} in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect my users to a page that its format is `/folder/{param1}/{param2}` in my web.php file. This is the code I'm using for that:

```
return redirect()->action(
                "Controller@function", ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2']
            );
```

But it gives me `Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: folder/{param1}/{param2}].`

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I even checked my syntax with Visual Studio Code and it seems that my syntax is fine. I also tried to do the same with `redirect()->route()` but I got the same error again.

**Additional information:**

This is how my URL is defined in web.php

```
Route::get('/folder/{param1}/{param2}','Controller@function');
```

And I am calling redirect() in another controller which is responsible for a search function.

Comment: where are  you calling this `redirect()->action()` method? is URL is get method? `return redirect(url('folder/value1/value2'))` have you tried like this.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, my URL is defined by ```Route::get('/folder/{param1}/{param2}','Controller');``` in web.php. The second parameter is optional in my function by the way.

Comment: Your web.php is correct. `Route::get('/folder/{param1}/{param2}','Controller@function');`  but where you call this url? how?

Comment: I call it in a controller that is responsible for searching. I want to redirect my user to that URL and I want to pass param1 to be something that is determined by the search result. param2 is optional, but I am still passing it just in case and yet I get a missing required parameters error! :/

Comment: I think @DilipHirapara meant to say ```Route::get('/folder/{param1}/{param2}','Controller');```  is not correct. You need to specify the function on the controller that will handle calls to the route. ie ```Controller@handlingFunction``` and that method should look like ```handlingFunction($param1, $param2)```

Comment: @KurtFriars Sorry, my bad. I have specified it. I just forgot to type it. I can't edit my comment now, but it should've been ```Route::get('/folder/{param1}/{param2}','Controller@function');```

Comment: In web,php `Route::get('/folder/{param1}/{param2}','Controller@function');` and in controller `return redirect('folder/value2/value2');`

Comment: @DilipHirapara Thanks. That worked. Please post it as an answer so my question will become resolved.

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled, while your initial approach with redirect()->action(...) shouldn't work. Maybe you need to look at artisan route:list to see if you have duplicates or anything..?

Comment: Can you also post the Controller function head?

Comment: @wschopohl I agree with you. I don't understand it either. I can't see duplicates in route:list which makes it even more confusing. What do you mean by the Controller function head? Like ```public function blah($param1, $param2 = null ){}``` ?

Comment: Exactly, just wanted to make sure, that you have both parameters in the function definition. Maybe a artisan route:clear might help? Or a composer dump, but that's pretty desperate.. Just for checking: Would a redirect to another action work?

Comment: Yeah. I have a similar search function for another part of my app and it works fine without issues. Would artisan route:clear remove all of my routes? I mean I don't want to lose any data of what I have developed so far.

Comment: btw `param2` is not optional, it is required based on the Route definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **web.php**

```
Route::get('/folder/{param1}/{param2}','Controller@function');
```

and in controller

```
return redirect('folder/value2/value2');
```